# How would I organise a clustered set of 2D coordinates into groups of close together sets?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, geometry

I have a large amount of 2D sets of coordinates on a 6000x6000 plane (2116 sets), available here: http://pastebin.com/kiMQi7yu (the context isn't really important so I just pasted the raw data).

I need to write an algorithm to group together coordinates that are close to each other by some threshold. The coordinates in my list are already in groups on that plane, but the order is very scattered.

Despite this task being rather brain-melting to me at first, I didn't admit defeat instantly; this is what I tried:

First sort the list by the Y value, then sort it by the X value. Run through the list checking the distance between the current set and the previous. If they are close enough (100 units) then add them to the same group.

This method didn't really work out (as I expected). There are still objects that are pretty close that are in different groups, because I'm only comparing the next set in the list and the list is sorted by the X position.

I'm out of ideas! The language I'm using is C but I suppose that's not really relevant since all I need is an idea for how the algorithm should work. Thanks!

Comment: Each point (x,y) should end up in one cluster only?

Comment: Yeah, the coordinates need to be separated into files for easier management/development (the coordinates are objects in an 3D environment however the Z doesn't matter hence why it's not in the coordinate sets).

Answer (score 2):

Though I haven't looked at the data set, it seems that you already know how many groups there are. Have you considered using k means? http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

Comment: I didn't know of that, I'll look into it but I don't know how many clusters/groups there are.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just thinking this along while I write.

1. Tile the "arena" with squares that have the diameter of your distance (200) as their diagonal.
2. If there are any points within a square (x,y), they are tentatively part of Cluster(x,y).
3. Within each square (x,y), there are (up to) 4 areas where the circles of Cluster(x-1,y), Cluster(x+1,y), Cluster(x, y-1) and Cluster(x,y+1) overlap "into" the square; of these consider only those Clusters that are tentatively non-empty.
4. If all points of Cluster(x,y) are in the (up to 4) overlapping segments of non-empty neighbouring clusters: reallocate these points to the pertaining Cluster and remove Cluster(x,y) from the set of non-empty Clusters.

**Added later:** Regarding 3., the set of points to be investigated for one neighbour can be coarsely but quickly (!) determined by looking at the rectangle enclosing the segment. [End of addition]

This is just an idea - I can't claim that I've ever done anything remotely like this.

Comment: Since the size of the coordinates is known as relatively small, this seems like a fair direction to go. Could also use a quad tree (more like a 9-tree to get the 8 surrounding it) instead.

Answer (score 1):

A simple, often used method for spatially grouping points, is to calculate the distance between each unique pair of points. If the distance does not exceed some predefined limit, then the points belong to the same group.

One way to think about this algorithm, is to consider each point as a limit-diameter ball (made of soft foam, so that balls can intersect each other). All balls that are in contact belong to the same group.

In practice, you calculate the squared distance, (x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup>, to avoid the relatively slow square root operation. (Just remember to square the limit, too.)

To track which group each point belongs to, a [disjoint-set data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) is used.

If you have many points (a few thousand is *not* many), you can use partitioning or other methods to limit the number of pairs to consider. Partitioning is probably the most used, as it is very simple to implement: just divide the space into squares of limit size, and then you only need to consider points within each square, and between points in neighboring squares.

I wrote a small awk script to find the groups (no partitioning, about 84 lines or awk code, also numbers the groups consecutively from 1 onwards, and outputs each input point, the group number, and the number of points in each group). Here's the results summarized:

```
 Limit  Singles   Pairs Triplets Clusters (of four or more points)
  1.0     1313     290       29       24
  2.0     1062     234       50       52
  3.0      904     179       53       75
  4.0      767     174       55       81
  5.0      638     173       52       84
 10.0      272      99       41       99
 20.0       66      20        8       68
 50.0       21      11        3       39
100.0       13       6        2       29
200.0        6       5        0       23
300.0        3       1        0       20
400.0        1       0        0       18
500.0        0       0        0       15
```

where Limit is the maximum distance at which the points are considered to belong to the same group.

If the data set is very detailed, you can have intertwined but separate groups. You can easily have a separate group in the hole of a donut-shaped group (or hollow ball in 3D). This is important to remember, so you don't make wrong assumptions on *how* the groups are separated.

Questions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a space-filling-curve, I.e a z curve a.k.a morton curve. Basically you translate x-and y value to binary and then concatenate th,e coordinates. The spatial index puts together close coordinates.  You can verify it with the upper bounds and the mostsignificant bits.